# cannot find command I installed from cygwin - can't run ddrescue that I installed

Tags: cygwin

I ran https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe  and installed ddrescue

here is some info from cygwin and from cmd so you see where the file is and the paths.

[image]

```
user@hp-probook1 ~
$ PATH=$PATH:/bin

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/blah:/usr/bin:/bin

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ ddrescue
-bash: ddrescue: command not found

user@hp-probook1 ~
$
```

and

```
C:\cygwin>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\cygwin

20/04/2020  22:48    <DIR>          .
20/04/2020  22:48    <DIR>          ..
05/11/2020  02:29    <DIR>          bin
14/03/2020  01:02            53,342 Cygwin-Terminal.ico
14/03/2020  00:59                88 Cygwin.bat
14/03/2020  01:02           157,097 Cygwin.ico
14/03/2020  00:59    <DIR>          dev
05/11/2020  02:29    <DIR>          etc
22/04/2020  10:00    <DIR>          home
20/04/2020  22:48    <DIR>          lib
14/03/2020  00:35    <DIR>          pk
20/04/2020  22:48    <DIR>          sbin
20/04/2020  22:46         1,352,723 setup-x86_64.exe
14/03/2020  00:59    <DIR>          tmp
14/03/2020  00:58    <DIR>          usr
14/03/2020  00:58    <DIR>          var
               4 File(s)      1,563,250 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  19,118,116,864 bytes free

C:\cygwin>dir bin\dd*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\cygwin\bin

03/02/2017  19:40            83,987 dd.exe
03/04/2020  16:17           118,291 ddrescue.exe
03/04/2020  16:17            59,411 ddrescuelog.exe
               3 File(s)        261,689 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  19,118,116,864 bytes free

C:\cygwin>
```

**added info**

```
user@hp-probook1 ~
$ which ddrescue
which: no ddrescue in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/blah)

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ echo  $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/blah

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ PATH=$PATH:/bin

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ which ddrescue
which: no ddrescue in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/blah:/bin)

user@hp-probook1 ~
$
```

and

```
user@hp-probook1 /bin
$ cd /bin

user@hp-probook1 /bin
$ ls dd*
dd.exe

user@hp-probook1 /bin
$

user@hp-probook1 /bin
$ cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin

user@hp-probook1 /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$ ls ddrescue
ddrescue

user@hp-probook1 /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$ ddrescue --help
-bash: ddrescue: command not found

user@hp-probook1 /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$ ./ddrescue --help
ddrescue: Both input and output files must be specified.
Try '/usr/bin/ddrescue --help' for more information.

user@hp-probook1 /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$ ls /usr/bin/ddrescue
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/ddrescue': No such file or directory

user@hp-probook1 /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
$
```

Comment: Once you got to the directory `./ddrescue` instead of `ddrescue`? What does `which ddrescue` show you? What are you trying to recover?  I wouldn't use a wrapper linux tool from windows.  I would either use testdisk or boot from an linux live boot and recover from there.  BTW, WSL kicks butt.. you will never use Cygwin again.

Comment: I've added "which" output and attempts to get to the directory and running it  b) cygwin and ddrescue are fine when ddrescue installs right , strange that it hasn't installed right. I could use a linux VM or boot linux off USB and run ddrescue, but have always been fine with cygwin and ddrescue before. A hard drive is possibly near death so i'd like to run ddrescue (which is like dd but with a progress bar and maybe some other features).  I normally run that, get an image, then use testdisk on the image.    I'm on Win7. Not sure how good/bad WSL is on that?

Comment: Hrrrmmm.. me neither :P  In your situation I usually boot from a live disk and ddrescue the drive to somewhere else.. then use testdisk.  I hate CYGWIN so I am probably not a good person to help here :)

Answer (score 0):

It works now..

I realised that not only could it not run ddrescue, it couldn't run ssh either.. despite me installing ssh.  Reinstalling cygwin the normal way didn't work.

Cygwin naturally requires two directories, one for it and one for packages..
I had a directory for cygwin e.g. c:\cygwin and one for the packages c:\cygwinpk

What I did to get it to work was  I renamed c:\cygwin to c:\oldcygwin, and I renamed c:\cygwinpk to c:\oldcygwinpk

I downloaded cygwin setup (64bit of course 'cos 32-bit is from eons ago, and even my fairly old computers are 64bit).   Then I installed cygwin

And that made the difference, forcing cygwin to really install fresh.

I had to rename old cygwin directories before reinstalling cygwin, for it to work.

Now as you see it works

```
user@hp-probook1 ~
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/tech/something:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Network Moni
tor 3:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/blah

user@hp-probook1 ~
$


user@hp-probook1 ~
$ ddrescue
ddrescue: Both input and output files must be specified.
Try 'ddrescue --help' for more information.

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ which ddrescue
/usr/bin/ddrescue

user@hp-probook1 ~
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh

user@hp-probook1 ~
$
```

That's on a Windows 7 machine.. an alternative to that on Win7 would be a Virtual Machine.   Windows 10 has another option, a very snazzy functional "WSL"(windows subsystem for linux) that lets you set up e.g. an Ubuntu system. And the c drive as seen in windows is visible in /mnt/c.  just like in cygwin it is in /cygdrive/c.  So people may use cygwin less in Win10.  As WSL *nix programs seem a bit more native to *nix, you'd always be getting the latest versions that any *nix user would get.

Comment: I actually moved to Windows 10 just to see if WSL2 could replace Cygwin, but turns out WSL2 [doesn't and likely never will](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/689) support block devices, so securely wiping a disk with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` or using `ddrescue` directly on the disk instead of the mounted partition will never work, plus a lot of other use cases that require access to the device itself. WSL2 is also a LOT slower than Cygwin. I have both of them installed side-by-side on Windows 10 and use Cygwin almost exclusively.